# Why pandas.series.describe and pandas.series.describe() give different results?

Tags: python, pandas, methods, series

Why pandas.series.describe and pandas.series.describe() give different results?

How does a method call work without the braces? Is it actually a method call or an attribute of the pandas.series class?

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question.  In order for it to be a method call it must have the parentheses.  If it doesn't have them, it's just an attribute.  A method is just an attribute that you can call.  So `obj.meth` is the method itself; `obj.meth()` actually *calls* the method.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  So, it's a same name for an attribute and method in pandas series.

Comment: A method *is* an attribute; it's just an attribute that you can call.  The parentheses are what makes it a call.  It's not like there's an attribute and then a method with the same name.  The attribute value is the method, and if you use `()` then you call it.

Comment: Right! I was looking for it in pandas source code, you explained it very well. Thanks again.